# Function inside resize function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

i have this piece of code.

First i'm setting some heights - the code works on load and on resize.
However, setting heights based on the highest item it doesn't work on resize, but only on load. Can you give me an advice?

```
$(window).resize(function () {
// speakers - height equal to width

var imgwidth = $('.speakers-section-items-item-image').width();
$('.speakers-section-items-item-image').css({'height': imgwidth + 'px'});
var height = $('.executive-section-items-item-img').height();
$('.executive-section-items-item-list').css({'line-height': height + 'px'});
var heightTeam = $('.team-section-items-item-img').height();
$('.team-section-items-item-meta-last').css({'line-height': heightTeam + 'px'});
```

// set heights based on the highest item

```
var maxHeightTeam = -1;

$('.team-section-items-item').each(function () {
    maxHeightTeam = maxHeightTeam > $(this).height() ? maxHeightTeam : $(this).height();
});

$('.team-section-items-item').each(function () {
    $(this).height(maxHeightTeam);
});

var maxHeightExecutive = -1;

$('.executive-section-items-item').each(function () {
    maxHeightExecutive = maxHeightExecutive > $(this).height() ? maxHeightExecutive : $(this).height();
});

$('.executive-section-items-item').each(function () {
    $(this).height(maxHeightExecutive);
});

var maxHeightSpeakers = -1;

$('.speakers-section-items-item').each(function () {
    maxHeightSpeakers = maxHeightSpeakers > $(this).height() ? maxHeightSpeakers : $(this).height();
});

$('.speakers-section-items-item').each(function () {
    $(this).height(maxHeightSpeakers);
});

}).resize();
```